# Apache Tomcat showing incorrect version after upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, java-11, tomcat9

I was using Apache tomcat 9.0.44 earlier and due to some security vulnerabilities I've upgraded it to 9.0.62 now.

/bin/Version.bat shows correct version now 9.0.62

[image]

Also checked registry keys and it also shows correct version

[image]

Still on security dashboard we are getting "Vulnerable version of Apache Tomcat is installed 9.0.44"
All the applications are working fine.

I am not sure if during upgrade I've missed anything.
During upgrade from 9.0.44 to 9.0.62 these were the steps that I'd followed:-

1. From this URL https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-9.html#Upgrading_9.0.x checked the configuration file changes from Apache tomcat 9.0.44 to apache tomcat 9.0.62 and perform these changes in the configuration files as applicable.
2. Replaced all jar files from
   Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\lib to
   Tomcat9/lib directory
3. Updated Bootstrap.jar , Tomcat-juli jar , Tomcat9.exe , Tomcat9w.exe files from
   Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\bin to
   Tomcat9/bin

Also java -cp "catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo shows :-

[image]
could anyone please suggest what is incorrect in this case?

Comment: I can see that you have replaced all the jar files inside lib folder. But could you run this command from lib folder and confirm `java -cp "catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`

Comment: Hi Chetan, added a screenshot in the main description above, it also shows 9.0.62. Do you see any other discrepency?

Comment: Which VAPT tool are you using?

Comment: Rapid7 is the VAPT I am currently using

Comment: Could this be the issue?
https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3/issues/460

Comment: A good VAPT tool should give you the details on what base (e.g. file) it has detected the version.